# How can I receive returned "byte" data from C# project to PHP

Tags: c#, php

echo shell_exec("p5.exe 100 500");

This is my PHP code for executing an EXE file.

```
using System;

public class CommandLine2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        int i1 = int.Parse(args[0]);
        int i2 = int.Parse(args[1]);
        int len = i2 - i1;
        byte[] ar = new byte[len];
        for (int i = i1; i < i2; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = (byte) i;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my C# code.
What I want is, EXE code'll calculate "i2"-"i1". And exe file add theese numbers to byte array one by one.

My problem is, how can I read this byte array with PHP.
Can you help me?
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output your data from exe (stdout) and read it with php (from string, for example). It's the simplest way. PHP don't have standart libraries to work with memory of other programms.

Comment: Is there any way but printing the byte data to console and read it with php? Is there ONLY way to do that?

Comment: 1. Store data from app to file and read that file, 2. Store data to memcache, 3. Store data to database.
There are many different ways to make data exchange between two apps, but they all needs additional libraries.
You may not really OUTPUT data to console - you can use output buffer: ob_start();exec("a.exe"); $output = ob_get_contents(); ob_clean(); echo $output;